# Trouble connecting to local database with JDBC - no error after executing the code

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

This code isn't providing the connection to my local database. There is no error after executing the code below. Connecting with JDBC using DriverManager:

```
package first;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        Connection con=null;

        try{
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1","root","XXXXXXXX");

            if(con!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("connected successfully");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("not connected to database");``
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't swallow the `Exception`. Printing not connected to database, isn't particularly helpful. `e.printStackTrace();` is more likely to show you something meaningful.

Comment: Please [format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).  Hard to understand otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

When troubleshooting a connection string one of the first steps is to try to connect using another tool that allows a nice user interface for providing the connection information. In this case you could [MySql Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-new.html) which comes with the community edition of MySql. Once you have a solid connection using the tool you can then copy the connection string it uses to your code. This will help eliminate the connection string errors in your code.

In addition as @Elliot Frisch suggested outputting the stacktrace should give you some good information to help troubleshoot your connection string, as well.